# CSS position:fixed - position only correct when run locally

Tags: css, css-position

I'm using the following CSS to position a link:

```
position:fixed;
top:381;
right:265;
```

It works, and the link is correctly placed when I view the HTML files using a file:/// url, but when I put it up on a server and view it from there, the link appears in the top left corner of the screen instead. I've confirmed that the HTML page is loading the CSS file correctly, because it's loading the other style information just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to define a proper unit for your declaration. `top:381px; right:265px`

Comment: you have looked with firebug to the actual applied styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `px`

```
position: fixed;
top: 381px;
right: 265px;
```

Comment: @user1359209, you're welcome.  Don't forget to earn yourself more rep by accepting my answer.